# How to add file in NSIS from different folders

Tags: installation, nsis

I have the following already set up and working:

```
File file1.bat
File file2.xml
File common.file1.dll
File common.file2.dll
File common.file3.exe
```

What I would want, to avoid keeping the common files in the source directory, is reference them from the parent directory like so:

```
File file1.bat
File file2.xml
File ..\common.file1.dll
File ..\common.file2.dll
File ..\common.file3.exe
```

**Edit:** This actually works when I tried it again.

*But apparently, this is not recognized.

Is there another way to reference these files?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

File's are relative to the .nsi and ..\xyz should work...

Comment: You are right, it works! I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify separate output file paths and source file paths for the File command:

```
File /oname=$INSTDIR\common.file3.exe ..\common.file3.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an environment variable pointing to the folder where you want to keep your dependencies. Then use that environment var in your nsi script.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the  following line in your script:

```
File file1.bat
File file2.xml
SetOutpath "<source directory path>"
File common.file1.dll
File common.file2.dll
File common.file3.exe
```

Comment: Nope, that is not it, I think, because it does not allow `"..\"` which is what I intend to copy the common files from.